# How to use (python) virtual environments with ROS2?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to run a python node which has imported some dependencies installed in a python virtual environment (using virtualenv). I have followed this tutorial:
https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Using-Python-Packages/#installing-via-a-virtual-environment

The problem is that when I run the node, I have an import error ModuleNotFoundError, related to the packages installed in the virtual environment.

I have rclpy on the default system python. I do not know what further info I can add to help. Has any of you managed to work this out and have a nice python environment?
Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371083/how-to-use-(python)-virtual-environments-with-ros2?/) by [jeferrandiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/60816/jeferrandiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2021-02-04

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bekirbostanci](https://answers.ros.org/users/45026/bekirbostanci/) on 2021-02-04**:
Are you sure virtual env python activated?
After the open a new console you have to set virtual env source. Also I tried with anaconda and it worked

**Comment by [jeferrandiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/60816/jeferrandiz/) on 2021-02-04**:
Yes, I source the env as soon as I open a new console. I'll think to use anaconda too, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You need to check your `$PYTHONPATH` running `echo $PYTHONPATH`

This should show the path to your ROS distro, e.g. `opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages`, and the path to your environment packages `.../path-to-your-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

If the env-package path is not present, add it using `export PYTHONPATH='.../path-to-your-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages'`

Run `echo $PYTHONPATH` again, check that your env-package path is there, and try to run your node `ros2 run node...`,... this should work.

To avoid adding the env-package path to  `$PYTHONPATH` every single time, add `export PYTHONPATH='.../path-to-your-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages'` to your environment `activate` file.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [FabioArnez](https://answers.ros.org/users/69763/fabioarnez/) with karma: 76 on 2021-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jeferrandiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/60816/jeferrandiz/) on 2021-02-11**:
Thank you so much!! It worked by adding the path, you've saved one life :-)